# "Android SDK version not found" error when running Genymotion Android emulator from Appcelerator Studio

Tags: android, appcelerator, titanium-alloy, genymotion

When I try to run my Alloy app in the Genymotion Android emulator from Appcelerator Studio, I get the error "Android SDK version Android M (Preview) not found". As far as I can tell, I have that SDK version installed.

**Here is how I attempt to run it:**

[image: Run it]

**Here is the error I get:**

[image: Error message]

**It seems like I have the right SDK installed:**

[image: Installed SDKs]

**Update #1**

This is the `<android/>` element of my tiapp.xml:

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <tool-api-level>21</tool-api-level>
    <manifest>
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>
        <!-- other manifest entries -->
    </manifest>
</android>
```

Comment: What did you put as minSDK and targetSDK?

Comment: @Vannen Are minSDK and targetSDK configurations in Appcelerator Studio, or of Genymotion?

Comment: In the tiapp.xml file there should be a tag inside the android manifest section like this: `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>`

Comment: You will need to check what I'm going to say. Does the compilation succeeds if you put the targetSDK back to 21? I have heard in a recent android backstage podcast that the compilation will be successfully if you put the targetSdk to 22 but you will not be able to submit to the play store just yet. As far as I know the only ways to test Api22 apps is on the official android emulator or on nexuses with the M preview installed.

Comment: My tiapp.xml file was missing the manifest section, but I added it, as displayed in the update to my question. No change from before.

Comment: Could you try without the <tool-api-level> tag?

Comment: @FokkeZandbergen I tried with and without the <tool-api-level/> tag, and there is no difference.

Comment: It looks like for some reason it is trying to use the Android M preview SDK. Could you remove those? Or include the Titanium build logs here?

Comment: Try to change tiapp to AndroidManifest. Maybe it's just not recognizing it as a manifest. Tell me if this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to install build tools from Tools folder and platform tools from Tools (Preview Channel) folder.

Comment: @Kevin Albrecht Does my answer helped you?

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems you have API 22 installed but not API 21. You need 21 since your `targetSdkVersion` is set to 21.

Please install API 21 and see what it says then.

Answer (score -1):

See if the  emulator is installed in the sdk file.